# Hybris business process in running state

Tags: cron, sap-commerce-cloud, business-process-management

The order confirmation email did not get triggered after placing an order. Looking at the business processes for the order, none of them got triggered.

Things I check-listed:

- Restarted admin node
- Deleted all business processes that are in running state
- Looked for any failed feed in the hot folder
- Had a search for TaskExecutor-master in Hybris thread dumps - to identify which part is causing an issue, none found.
- The task.engine.loadonstartup = false.

None of the above worked.

Please help me resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved:

We had an issue with the cluster ID. All the nodes had the same cluster ID. This was caused due to a wrong deployment. We re-mediated it which fixed the issue.**